# How to increment variable directly in template binding in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, local-variables, angular-template

I have the following object:

```
  this.people = [{
        name: 'Douglas  Pace',
        title: 'Parcelivery Nailed The Efficiency',
        content: 'Since I installed this app, its always help me book every tickets I need like flight, concert, ' +
          'movie or hotel. I don\'t need to install different app for different ticket. The payment is also very easy',
        image: '../../assets/img/profile_pics/profile_pic.jpg',
        rate: '4.5',
        classActive: 'testimonials__selected-visible',
        active: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Naseebullah  Ahmadi',
        title: 'Parcelivery Nailed The Efficiency',
        content: 'Since I installed this app, its always help me book every tickets I need like flight, concert, ' +
          'movie or hotel. I don\'t need to install different app for different ticket. The payment is also very easy',
        image: '../../assets/img/profile_pics/profile_pic.jpg',
        rate: '4.5',
        classActive: '',
        active: false
      },
      {
        name: 'Haseebullah Ahmadi',
        title: 'Parcelivery Nailed The Efficiency',
        content: 'Since I installed this app, its always help me book every tickets I need like flight, concert, ' +
          'movie or hotel. I don\'t need to install different app for different ticket. The payment is also very easy',
        image: '../../assets/img/profile_pics/profile_pic.jpg',
        rate: '4.5',
        classActive: '',
        active: false
      }
    ];
```

and I am looping this in html like so:

```
  <ng-template ngFor let-person="$implicit" let-variable [ngForOf]="people">
          {{variable + 30}}
   <ng-template/>
```

My question is, is there a way of having a local variable and incrementing it by 30 for each element inside the ngfor in template binding? Rather than having methods to do the incrementing?

The issue that I have with incrementing the variable from methods is that i get the following error:

> Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has
>   changed after it was checked

Comment: which field of the array do you need to increment

Comment: Currently I just want to create a random variable that gets incremented. I dont want to be adding a field in the object and increment that. This is just to illustrate my question here. However Im using an api which I get objects back, so I cant be modifying that. @sachilaranawaka

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ng-template ngFor let-person="$implicit" let-variable [ngForOf]="people" let-i="index">
  <p *ngIf="i == 0">{{variable + 30}}</p>
  <p *ngIf="i > 0">{{variable + (30*i)}}</p>
<ng-template/>
```

By this you get the index starting from `0` to total length.

Comment: so for a collection of 3 items, the above returns `0, 30, 60`. Can i recieve `30, 60, 90`?

Comment: btw, when I print, the variable returns the current element inside the object, and the index, which is wrong.

Comment: what is the type of `variable`?  try to print index `i` alone and check getting correct value. u can use `*ngIf` to skip the 0

Comment: or you can do `(30*(i+1))` and you'll get `30 60 90`

Comment: Thank you @YordanNikolov Your partial solution did the trick :)